# Opengl texture upload of 16 bit data to not normalize

Tags: opengl, texture2d

I have 2 scenarios, one where there is a floating point array of data and another where there is a 16bit short data.  I'm uploading the texture data to the graphics card using the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, floatData);
```

and in the other case of the short

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_SHORT, shortData);
```

The problem I have is lets say I have a value of 512 stored.  When I upload the floatData array I get the expected 512 value inside the shader.  However when I use the shortData a value of 512 gets normalized to 512/65535.

So my question is there a way to instruct openGL to take my shortData array data and not do normalization upon it?

Comment: Does using `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` instead of `GL_RGBA` in the second case help?

Comment: It doesn't help for my scenario.  I think the best course of action right now is to just supply a normalization factor to the shader since I know which data type I'm trying to use.  Thanks for the suggestion :)